# How can I draw a first-order equation graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a linear equation graph of sensor values using matplotlib in Python.

There are parameters of A, B, C, D, STD,
I want to graph the output (y) against the sensor value (x).
This parameter is y=Ax+B if the sensor value is less than STD, and y=C(x-STD)+D if it is more than STD. As shown in the figure below, the position where the sensor value is output at 1-second intervals is expressed as a [red dot on the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa5FX.png).

How do I code this?

This is my code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
    
a = 0.1222
b = 66.268
c = 0.5200
d = 701.7080
STD = 5200

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)
y1 = a*x+b
y2 = c*(x*STD)+d
    
plt.plot(x, y1, label='y1=ax+b')
plt.plot(x, y2, label='y2=c(x*STD)+d')
    
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Graph of y1 and y2')
plt.legend()
    
plt.show()
```

Comment: `sensor value is less than STD`? In your code max(x) is 10, it is always less than STD

Comment: The x value and each parameter value are randomly inserted in the code, and the actual x value will move between 0 and 30, and examples of the actual parameters applied are A=27.363, B=0.8187, C=1.1051, D=13.4, and STD=0.46.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have 2 errors so you cannot get what you want:

- you put `x*STD` instead of `x-STD` into your equation
- you have the same limit for both plots so you get intersecting lines instead of a single line consisting of 2 segments. Also a limit `(-10, 10)` does not make much sense so it should be expanded.

Here is an example how a segmented line can be drawed:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = 0.1222
b = 66.268
c = 0.5200
d = 701.7080
STD = 5200
xmin = 0
xmax = 10000

x1 = np.linspace(xmin, STD, 1000)
x2 = np.linspace(STD, xmax, 1000)
y1 = a*x1 + b
y2 = c*(x2 - STD) + d

# both plots
plt.plot(x1, y1, label='ax + b')
plt.plot(x2, y2, label='c(x - STD) + d')

# arrow with STD
arrow_height = 1000
plt.arrow(STD, d + arrow_height, 5, -arrow_height, head_width=0.15*arrow_height, head_length=0.15*arrow_height, length_includes_head=True, fc='gray', ec='gray')
plt.text(STD, d + 1.05 * arrow_height, 'STD', color='gray', fontsize='large', ha='center', va='baseline')

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Graph of y1 and y2')
plt.legend()
    
plt.show()
```

You can add a red dot to it further, but the principle should be clear.

[image: Sample result]

Answer (score 0):

I am using your values provided in the comment. Updating the code like this will give you the two lines, the red dot and the horizontal and vertical lines as shown in the example. Note that... in this case, the red dot (x=1) is on the second line, but the code should handle both cases. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
    
a = 27.363
b = 0.8187
c = 1.1051
d = 13.4
STD = 0.46

x = np.linspace(0, 30, 1000)

y1 = [i*a+b for i in x if i<= STD]  ## y1 is from start till x=STD
y2 = [i*c*STD+d for i in x if i>= STD]  ## y2 is from x=STD till the end

##Note x is filtered to show based on length
plt.plot(x[:len(y1)], y1, label='y1=ax+b')
plt.plot(x[-len(y2):], y2, label='y2=c(x*STD)+d')

## Common variable for the position of the dot and lines
if max(x[:len(y1)]) >= 1:
    pos=a+b
else:
    pos=c*STD+d
    
xmin=plt.xlim()[0]
ymin=plt.ylim()[0]
plt.scatter(1, pos, c='red', s = 100, zorder=5) ## The red dot
plt.hlines(y=pos, xmin=xmin, xmax=1, ls=":", color='black')  ##Horizontal line
plt.xlim(left=xmin)
plt.vlines(x=1, ymin=ymin, ymax=pos, ls=":", color='black')  ##Vertical line
plt.ylim(bottom=ymin)
    
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Graph of y1 and y2')
plt.legend()
    
plt.show()
```

[image]